# How to make theme button affect whole page

Tags: html, css, themes

I have a dark theme/light theme button on my page but it has a blank space at the top of the page. I want to remove that blank space and want to look like effect is applying in whole page.

Here is the code for it (The top is HTML, the bottom is CSS):
http://pastebin.com/GL4vvUQN

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #222;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #222;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.nav ul li img {
  width: 12px;
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.nav ul li a,
visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #099;
}
.navhome {
  color: #099;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #099;
}
.navother {
  color: #ccc;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130%;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.bdaimg {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.bdaimg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.nu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.bdaimg2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.bdaimg2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
/*Light Switch*/

label {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px/25px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
}
label:hover {
  background: #ddca7e;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input#lightswitch {
  position: fixed;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
input#lightswitch + .content {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
}
/*Switched Off*/

input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  background-color: #222;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
}
input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  color: white;
}
input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Beijing Dance Academy</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bda.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="navother" href="Home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navother" href="CR.html">Cultural Revolution</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navhome" href="BDA.html">Beijing Dance Academy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navother" href="CNY.html">Chinese New Year</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="lightswitch">Light Switch</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lightswitch" />
  <div class="content">
    <img src="bda.png" alt="BDA" class="bdaimg">
    <p>
      <h2>Beijing Dance Academy</h2>
      Beijing Dance Academy, or BDA, was the first professional dance school founded in China, in 1954. The academy was helped by Soviet Russia in building the academy and the techniques they used to learn dance. Although Russia helped with the Beijing Dance
      Academy, China's repressive Communist government forbidded Russian presence in the school. The Beijing Dance Academy soon opened back up to all people from around the world when, in 1976, China's Communist leader, Mao Zedong, died.
      <br>
      <br>Several times a year, Beijing Dance Academy holds auditions to be accepted into the school, for more disadvantaged areas officals come around small towns and schools and pick out children of age, the academy initially only accepted students from
      ages 11 to 18 but eventually the age range expanded. They then test the student's basic body abilities. More than 2,000 children audition to be accepted into the academy but only 1 in every 20 make the cut. Majority of the children in the academy
      are Chinese but the academy has an additional program that allows international students to apply.
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>
    A Day in the Life of a Student
  </h3>
      A day of a Beijing Dance Academy student starts with basic warm-ups and stretches such as flexibility exercises and drills for turns and jumps. After breakfast, the students have a ballet technique class followed by character dance or pas de deux exercises.
      Then after lunch, the students study normal subjects such as mathematics or Chinese for 3 hours. In the afternoon, they have repertory classes or study or do homework. The Beijing Dance Academy is run for the whole week...
    </p>
    <p class="nu">
      INCLUDING SATURDAY AND SUNDAY!
      <img src="sadface.png" alt="SpongebobSadFace" class="bdaimg2">
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your img with src="bda.png" has a margin-top of 30px.
This is some strange behavior in html, it doesn't move the image down 30px but it moves the parent of the image down the 30px.
To solve you can either set the margin-top of the image to 0px and move it down with padding-top of the div, or you can set the display-property of the containing div to "display: inline-block". Like this:

```
.content {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 130%;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **negative margin** to remove that blank sapce like this:

```
 .content {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130%;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Here is the improved code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #222;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #222;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.nav ul li img {
  width: 12px;
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.nav ul li a,
visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #099;
}
.navhome {
  color: #099;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #099;
}
.navother {
  color: #ccc;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130%;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.bdaimg {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.bdaimg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.nu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.bdaimg2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.bdaimg2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
/*Light Switch*/

label {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px/25px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
}
label:hover {
  background: #ddca7e;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input#lightswitch {
  position: fixed;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
input#lightswitch + .content {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
}
/*Switched Off*/

input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  background-color: #222;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in;
}
input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  color: white;
}
input#lightswitch:checked + .content {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Beijing Dance Academy</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bda.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="navother" href="Home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navother" href="CR.html">Cultural Revolution</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navhome" href="BDA.html">Beijing Dance Academy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="navother" href="CNY.html">Chinese New Year</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="lightswitch">Light Switch</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lightswitch" />
  <div class="content">
    <img src="bda.png" alt="BDA" class="bdaimg">
    <p>
      <h2>Beijing Dance Academy</h2>
      Beijing Dance Academy, or BDA, was the first professional dance school founded in China, in 1954. The academy was helped by Soviet Russia in building the academy and the techniques they used to learn dance. Although Russia helped with the Beijing Dance
      Academy, China's repressive Communist government forbidded Russian presence in the school. The Beijing Dance Academy soon opened back up to all people from around the world when, in 1976, China's Communist leader, Mao Zedong, died.
      <br>
      <br>Several times a year, Beijing Dance Academy holds auditions to be accepted into the school, for more disadvantaged areas officals come around small towns and schools and pick out children of age, the academy initially only accepted students from
      ages 11 to 18 but eventually the age range expanded. They then test the student's basic body abilities. More than 2,000 children audition to be accepted into the academy but only 1 in every 20 make the cut. Majority of the children in the academy
      are Chinese but the academy has an additional program that allows international students to apply.
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>
    A Day in the Life of a Student
  </h3>
      A day of a Beijing Dance Academy student starts with basic warm-ups and stretches such as flexibility exercises and drills for turns and jumps. After breakfast, the students have a ballet technique class followed by character dance or pas de deux exercises.
      Then after lunch, the students study normal subjects such as mathematics or Chinese for 3 hours. In the afternoon, they have repertory classes or study or do homework. The Beijing Dance Academy is run for the whole week...
    </p>
    <p class="nu">
      INCLUDING SATURDAY AND SUNDAY!
      <img src="sadface.png" alt="SpongebobSadFace" class="bdaimg2">
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. You really helped!